# Disable dragscrollable for specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/mvlandys/jquery.dragscrollable) to have dragscrollable-behavior attached to some content elements. Now I need to disable this feature temporarily.

The plugins documentation does not offer such disable method so I tried these snippets, but without success:

```js
    // bind plugin dragscrollable
    $('.dragscrollable').dragscrollable();

    // remove the identifier class - still dragscrollable
    $('.dragscrollable').removeClass('dragscrollable');

    // unbind mousemove/mousedown event handler - still dragscrollable
    $('.dragscrollable').off('mousemove', 'mousedown');
```

However it seems impossible to achieve this feature to be disabled. Any suggestions? Is it a virus, once binded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Edit the plugin and add to the mouseMoveHandler:

```
mouseMoveHandler : function(event) { // User is dragging
  // optional disable handler
  if(lockDragscrollDisable == true) {
     return false;
  }

  // .. 
}
```

Set the variable lockDragscrollDisable to have this feature disabled.